# Automate the "generate scripts" task in SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking to automate the "generate scripts" task in SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

I see other questions with similar titles and also get different answers. But this I think is slightly different. I need to generate scripts for SPs/Functions/Views with `ALTER` option. I don't need to use `CREATE` command.

My scenario is I want to deploy my developer machine script to production. So mostly all SP/Functions/Views are already generated on production server. I only need to generate `ALTER` script to I can just execute it. Or is there any option to generate script in such a way that if an object does not exists then it will generate script with `CREATE` command, otherwise it will generate script with `ALTER` command.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There are other ways to backup the database, export data, set up replication between databases, generate database projects or version the database schema

Comment: It's a schema, not a script. Create a database project using SQL Server Database Tools (SSDT) and use its "Deploy" or "Schema Compare" functionality to apply changes to the project to target databses. Schema compare can detect differences and generate modification scripts between databases, or a database and the db project

Comment: Actually I want to deploy my updated objects(SPs etc) to other machines. I used term production server, but in my case I have to deploy to 4/5 different machines for some reason. So target is to update all these machines with latest objects definitions that I have on my local server.